# Error using t.test - not enough 'x' observations

Tags: r, p-value

I have data where methylation has been measured.

The data: `data.frame`, `900` observations `x 70` patients [30 ctrl, 40 case], all values are `numeric`, no `NA`s.

I use the following code:

```
group <- function(dFrame,toMatch)
{
  matches <- unique (grep(paste(toMatch,collapse="|"), 
                      colnames(dFrame), value=TRUE))
  return(dFrame[matches])
}

pValue <- sapply(methySample, function(x) t.test( group (x,'case'),group (x,'ctrl'))$p.value)


Error in t.test.default(group (x, "case"), group (x, "ctrl")) : 
  not enough 'x' observations
```

I want pValue to be a vector with one entry for each observation-row.

EDIT2: Here is an example - shortened but you should get the idea:

```
    case_01     case_02     case_03     ctrl_01     ctrl_02    ...
1   0.876729    0.8760000   0.8835130   0.8999369   0.8642505
2   0.8270763   0.7983686   0.8092107   0.8610273   0.8475543
3   0.2591350   0.2829770   0.2735919   0.2556579   0.2735417
4   0.8181337   0.8007408   0.7808821   0.8097073   0.7511147
5   0.6217151   0.6061754   0.5850365   0.6151368   0.5680856
6   0.6943685   0.7605200   0.6855676   0.6687362   0.7320926
...
```

Maybe someone here can help me to figure out what went wrong - maybe I am missing something obvious here. I have already seen other posts considering this error message but the answers were like 'do you have NAs in your data?' 'oh yea!' - this does not apply for my problem..
Thank you!

Comment: is `methySample` a data frame?

Comment: yes: > class(methySample)
[1] "data.frame"

Comment: Then sapply is applying the provided function to each column of methly sample, which I suspect is not what you want.  Is it the case that each column of methylSample is the data from a particular individual (case or control) and the rows are all the observations for a single methylation site?

Comment: Can you give a little more info on the structure of `methySample`, like `head(methySample)` or `str(methySample)`?  Also, is your goal a t test (p-value) per each of the 70 patients?

Comment: The observations are made for different methylation sites - I want to look for 'significant' differences between ctrl and case group. I wanted pValue to be a vector  [Sorry I will edit this accordingly in the question]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that you want to apply the the t-test for each row in your data.frame and the fields are labeled 'case1','control1', etc.

```
methySample  <-  
    data.frame(case1=rnorm(10),
               case2=rnorm(10),
               control1=rnorm(10),
               control2=rnorm(10))

# identify the fields that are labeled 'case' and 'control'
caseFields <- grep('case',colnames(methySample), value=TRUE)
controlFields <- grep('control',colnames(methySample), value=TRUE)

# apply the t-test for each row (margin = 1)
apply(methySample,
      1,
      function(x)
          t.test(x[caseFields],
                 x[controlFields])$p.value)
```

If you're still having trouble, this bit of code is equivalent and probably easier to debug:

```
pValue <- numeric(0)
for(i in seq(nrow(methySample)))
    pValue  <-  c(pValue,
                  t.test(methySample[i,caseFields],
                         methySample[i,controlFields])$p.value)
```

Comment: That is pretty much the exact same code I was about to put down.  Too slow on my part.

Comment: Yes this is what I want and it works for your example - still have the `not enough 'x' observations` with my data though. Nevertheless this is the correct answer as soon as I fix the data I guess! Thank you two :)

Comment: The problem was the way I separated the ctrl and case group - it works now!